# Increasing Timeout for WCF hosted on iis7

Tags: wcf, iis-7, timeout

I have a WCF hosted on IIS7. When I try to consume a service that takes more than 90 seconds to produce results, it times out after 90 second.

1. In web config, I have increased my executionTimeout to 900 seconds

> ```
>      <system.web>  
>         <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />  
>         <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="900" shutdownTimeout="900" maxRequestLength="2097152" enable="true"/>  
>         <pages>  
>           <namespaces>  
>             <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>  
>             <add namespace="System.ServiceModel"/>  
>              <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web"/>  
>           </namespaces>  
>         </pages>  
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>  
>     <trace enabled ="true" pageOutput ="true" requestLimit ="20" traceMode="SortByTime" />    
>      </system.web>
> ```

1. On the IIS side, I have set **scriptTimeout** to 00:05:10. (Default Website->ASP->Limits Properties->scriptTimeout)
2. In Application Pools, Advanced Settings, I have set **Ping Maximum Response Time** to 300 seconds (as well as **Shutdown Time Limit**. Though I don't think this helps.)

Even though I have increased every timeout variable I could find to over 90 second, my service still times out at 90 seconds.

Anyone know a timeout I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I took this from my config on my TEST server... this works. You're definitely going to want to change these values.

```
    <binding name="tcp_unsecured_HighLimit" closeTimeout="23:59:59" openTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59" sendTimeout="23:59:59" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="104857600" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: My default Web.config created by Visual Studio 2012 did not include any bindings or services. I was able to add them, but they are making no difference on how the service runs. It still times out in 90 seconds. (I can't even reduce the time to less than that with these configs).

Comment: Make sure you add these settings to you clients config also! These settings should be for the service AND client.